# Variadic template function to determine function pointer return type

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I have a variadic template function that takes an indirect function pointer (and its parameters) and invokes it (shown below). I was wondering how to modify this function so that it can have the proper return type matching the indirect function pointer it is invoking?

```
typedef UINT(APIENTRY *PFNFOO)(UINT, double);

class Foo
{
public:
    static UINT APIENTRY pfnFoo(UINT x, double y)
    {
        return (UINT)(x*y);
    }
};

template<typename PFN, typename... ARGS>
inline void CallFunc(void* pfn, const ARGS&... args)
{
    reinterpret_cast<PFN>(pfn) (args...);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PFNFOO pfn = &Foo::pfnFoo;

    CallFunc<PFNFOO>(pfn, 100, 0.5f);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the following but it complained that `error C2782: 'RET CallFunc(RET (__cdecl *)(ARGS...),const ARGS &...)' : template parameter 'ARGS' is ambiguous.` I think I am just missing the proper syntax so I would appreciate help here.

```
template<typename PFN, typename RET, typename... ARGS>
inline RET CallFunc(RET(*pfn)(ARGS...), const ARGS&... args)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<PFN>(pfn) (args...);
}

auto x = CallFunc<PFNFOO>(pfn, 100, 0.5f);
```

Comment: The syntax isn't the only thing that is wrong. Even when you get that right the function expects `UINT,double` and you're passing it  `int,float`. Because the types of the arguments are used when deducing the type of the function pointer they won't (and can't) match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow full deduction, you may use the following: ([live example](https://ideone.com/v5dG5X))

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Params, typename...Args>
inline Ret CallFunc(Ret(*pfn)(Params...), Args&&... args)
{
    return (*pfn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And then call it:

```
CallFunc(&Foo::pfnFoo, 100, 0.5f); // float will be converted into double in CallFunc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function expects a `UINT` and `double` as arguments, while you call it with `int` and `float`, so there is a mismatch between the types of `PFNFOO`'s arguments, and the actual arguments you pass to `CallFunc`. Furthermore, there's no need to specify the function pointer type explicitly, let the compiler deduce it. Your template can be simplified to:

```
template<typename RET, typename... ARGS>
inline RET CallFunc(RET(*pfn)(ARGS...), ARGS&&... args)
{
    return (*pfn)(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
}
```

Usage:

```
CallFunc(&Foo::pfnFoo, 100U, 0.5);
```

And if you want to pass it an `int` and a `float`, just specify the argument types explicitly.

```
CallFunc<UINT, UINT, double>(&Foo::pfnFoo, 100, 0.5f);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09b31eb949dbed04)